# R: How to add a specific date to a time column

Tags: r, date, time, time-series

I have time series data with a known start date, but my datafile just contains a time column. I would like to add a date column (julian date) with the starting date, which should refer to my time column and automatically change the date to the next day after midnight.

These are the first 20 rows of my dataset, I usually have 8 measurements per second, but for the first one, it could be less (like here, it's just 7, so no regular intervalls). I would now like to add a column with 08.04.2010 as starting date.

```
head(dat)
       Time Surge  Sway Heave  Press  Comp1   Comp2 Comp3 Temp
1  20:30:01 -0.36 -0.52  1.00     NA  41.12  -68.59  4.30   NA
2  20:30:01 -0.48 -0.50  0.92     NA -45.69 -122.72  5.96   NA
3  20:30:01 -0.55 -0.47  0.95     NA -53.57  -67.65  2.69   NA
4  20:30:01 -0.65 -0.51  1.00 811.06 -55.69  -67.02  3.82   NA
5  20:30:01 -0.51 -0.54  1.01     NA -45.12  -67.18  2.97   NA
6  20:30:01 -0.55 -0.51  1.00     NA -48.80  -66.34  5.41   NA
7  20:30:01 -0.65 -0.53  1.01     NA -64.64  -66.26  4.59   NA
8  20:30:02 -0.46 -0.55  1.03 810.52 -22.25  -67.13  3.59 8.41
9  20:30:02 -0.54 -0.48  1.01     NA -41.91  -66.81  5.29   NA
10 20:30:02 -0.56 -0.52  1.06     NA -45.45  -67.11  3.40   NA
11 20:30:02 -0.57 -0.52  1.04     NA -40.60  -67.82  4.13   NA
12 20:30:02 -0.62 -0.49  1.02 810.76 -52.42  -67.98  2.60   NA
13 20:30:02 -0.43 -0.49  1.01     NA -46.92  -67.84  2.92   NA
14 20:30:02 -0.65 -0.52  1.02     NA -28.02  -66.26  5.06   NA
15 20:30:02 -0.61 -0.51  1.03     NA -42.43  -67.51  4.06   NA
16 20:30:03 -0.58 -0.53  1.05 810.98 -45.55  -67.72  4.74 8.42
17 20:30:03 -0.64 -0.58  1.01     NA -65.28  -67.96  3.09   NA
18 20:30:03 -0.50 -0.52  1.05     NA -47.14  -67.84  4.89   NA
19 20:30:03 -0.51 -0.53  1.03     NA -57.48  -67.47  4.70   NA
20 20:30:03 -0.54 -0.52  1.02 810.89 -34.09  -67.86  4.58   NA
```

Many thanks for help!!

Pat

Comment: Please provide a _minimal and more representative_ data set, i.e. with a few (two or so) times before midnight and a few times after midnight. Please also show us the code you have tried and why it didn't meet your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DF <- data.frame(time = c("23:58:00", "23:59:00", "00:00:00", "00:01:00", "23:59:00", "00:00:00"),
                 x=1:6)

DF$julian <- cumsum(DF$time == "00:00:00") + 1

#      time x julian
#1 23:58:00 1      1
#2 23:59:00 2      1
#3 00:00:00 3      2
#4 00:01:00 4      2
#5 23:59:00 5      2
#6 00:00:00 6      3

DF$date <- cumsum(DF$time == "00:00:00") + as.Date("2010-04-08")
#       time x julian       date
# 1 23:58:00 1      1 2010-04-08
# 2 23:59:00 2      1 2010-04-08
# 3 00:00:00 3      2 2010-04-09
# 4 00:01:00 4      2 2010-04-09
# 5 23:59:00 5      2 2010-04-09
# 6 00:00:00 6      3 2010-04-10
```

Comment: Hi Roland, I just noticed that I have a problem with that code: Since I have 8 measurements per second, I have 8 times 00:00:00 before the next day starts. Do you know how I can tell R not to count these 8 times 00:00:00 as seperate days but rather to start at 00:00:01 with the next day (but again I have 00:00:01 times 8, so it shouldn't count these as seperate days). I tried some amendments to the code but couldn't solve the problem...

Comment: `cumsum(DF$time == "00:00:00") %/% 8`?

Comment: Hallelujah! That works, thank you!!! However, the first day starts at 0 now, maybe there is a way around this?